# leaflet - Using 'new' argument or without 'new' argument

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a question about using 'new' argument for leaflet and not using 'new' argument for
leaflet objects.

As far as I understood about 'new' argument,
new argument is for creating an object by running class in javascript.

Hence, I guessed,

if I use 'new' like,

```
var polilines = new L.polyline([lat,lon]).addTo(mymap)
console.log(polilines)
```

I could see the newly created object by polyline class while I can't see the
object if I type like,

```
var polilines = L.polyline([lat,lon]).addTo(mymap)
console.log(polilines)
```

However, in both cases, I could see the object that leaflet generated.

So I think, there is no reason to code like,

```
var something = new L.somefunctionalities
```

at all.

Did I miss anything?

Please feel free to give me some opinions or observations.

Thank you in advance.

P.S
It has nothing to do with L.tilelayer or L.Tilelayer

Comment: you don't need use 'new' here, if you want use 'new' to create new instance you should use next construction: let objInstance = new ClassName(); where ClassName is function and constructor of this class

Comment: @BS100: despite you ask for L.Polyline, I confirm Ivan's comment that it is exactly the same explanation as for Leaflet Tile Layer. `L.polyline` and `new L.Polyline` do the same thing by design for convenience (as explained in the linked post). `new L.polyline` _may_ work but is not designed by Leaflet code to be used as is.